# Does the linear combination of the quantile $\alpha F^{-1}(\tau)+\beta G^{-1}(\tau)$ still a quantile

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

$F(x)$ and $G(y)$ are distribution functions. 
Define the $\tau$th quantile for cdf $F(x)$, $G(y)$ as
$$\xi_\tau\equiv F^{-1}(\tau)=\inf\{x:F(x)\ge \tau\}$$
and
$$\eta_\tau\equiv G^{-1}(\tau)=\inf\{y:G(y)\ge \tau\}.$$
Does the linear combination of the quantile, say, $\alpha F^{-1}(\tau)+\beta G^{-1}(\tau)$ still a quantile of some cdf? That is, does there exist a cdf $H(z)$ s.t.
$$H^{-1}(\tau)=\alpha F^{-1}(\tau)+\beta G^{-1}(\tau)?$$
Do we need some constraints about $\alpha$ and $\beta$, say, $\alpha,\beta>0$ and $\alpha+\beta=1$?

Comment: Those conditions are the sufficient (and morally the correct conditions).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I take your comment to mean that in "nontypical" cases they may not be necessary. Can you give an example?

Comment: As a trivial example showing that the conditions might not be be necessary, if $F$ and $G$ are equal, then $2F^{-1}-G^{-1}$ works; or if $H^{-1}=1/2(F^{-1}+G^{-1})$ then $2H^{-1}-G^{-1}$ works.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Do we need $\alpha+\beta=1$? Since $\alpha,\beta>0$ is enough to make $\alpha F^{-1}(\tau)+\beta G^{-1}(\tau)$ be monotonically increasing. And is the monotonically increasing of $\alpha F^{-1}(\tau)+\beta G^{-1}(\tau)$  enough to find a corresponding distribution function s.t. $H^{-1}(\tau)=\alpha F^{-1}(\tau)+\beta G^{-1}(\tau)$?

Comment: You need the limit as $\tau$ approaches infinity to be 1, so yes: $\alpha+\beta$ must be 1.

Comment: No, we do not need $\alpha+\beta=1$. Eg: let $x$ be distributed uniformly on [0,1], let $y=2x^2$, then $\alpha=3,\ \beta =5$ gives the quantile function for $3x + 10x^2$.

Comment: Indeed, doesn't any right-continuous nondecreasing function $g$ with domain $[0,1]$ define a quantile function? (Just check that $g(U)$, for $U$ a standard uniform random variable defines a random variable with cdf $g^{-1}$, the (right-) generalized inverse function of $g$)?

Comment: @StephanSturm, almost, but the domain should be $(0,1)$ to allow for unbounded distributions.

Comment: @MattF. Agrred.